# extract substrings starting with same pattern in a file

Tags: linux

I have a fileA.txt which contains strings:

```
>AMP_16 RS0247 CENPF__ENST00000366955.7__3251__30__0.43333__66.8488__1 RS0255
>AMP_16 RS0332 CENPF__ENST00000366955.7__2262__30__0.43333__67.9513__1 RS0451
>AMP_16 RS0332 CENPF__ENST00000366955.7__1108__30__0.43333__67.4673__1 RS0247
and so on .....
```

I would like to extract all the substring which start with RS
Output:

```
RS0247_RS0255
RS0332_RS0451
RS0332_RS0247
```

I tried something like this:

```
while read line
do
        for word in $line
        do
                if [[ "$word" =~ ^RS ]]
                then
                        [ -z "$str" ] && str="$word"
                fi
        done
done < fileA.txt

echo "$str"
```

However I only get the first string RS0247 printed out when I do echo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the three sample lines pasted above in the file `f`...

Assuming a fixed format:

```
awk '{print $2"_"$4}' f
RS0247_RS0255
RS0332_RS0451
RS0332_RS0247
```

Assuming a flexible format (and that you're only interested in the first two occurrences of fields that start with `RS`:

```
awk '{f=1;for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/^RS/){a[f]=$i;f++}}print a[1]"_"a[2]}' f
RS0247_RS0255
RS0332_RS0451
RS0332_RS0247
```

**Edit 1:**

And assuming that you want your own script patched rather than an efficient solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
        str=""
        for word in $line
        do
                if [[ "$word" =~ ^RS ]]
                then
                        if [[ -z $str ]]
                        then
                                str=$word
                        else
                                str+="_${word}"
                        fi
                fi
        done
        echo "$str"
done < fileA.txt
```

**Edit 2:**

In terms of efficiency; I copied and pasted those 3 lines into fileA.txt 60 times (180 lines total).  The runtimes for the three attempts above in the same order are:

- real    0m0.002s
- real    0m0.002s
- real    0m0.011s

Comment: all good, I wanted to keep my code, your edit to the original code was useful and worked well

Comment: Pleased to hear =}